# Presentation style using beamer

Tags: beamer, beamerarticle

Anyone please suggest how can i get the present layout using beamer LaTeX. I want the style as marked (radio buttons for page by page) in yellow circle at the top of the page. Will be helpful if anyone can give best solution

[image: Beamer presention style]

Comment: I would suggest singapore

Comment: Please tell us how the headers "Proof Techniques", "Proof by Induction", and "Evaluation of Proposed Proofs" are generated.